# ASP.NET Core API Error: "Route exceeds the maximum number of allowed segments of 28"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been replacing an old asp.net API and rewriting it in .net core to implement swagger.
In the old version there was a get route with FIFTY SEVEN path segment parameters:

```
[WebGet(
UriTemplate =
"/MyHappyLittleController/{var1_}/{var2_}/{var3_}/{var4_}/{var5_}/{var6_}/{var7_}" +       
"/{C01_}/{C02_}/{C03_}/{C04_}/{C05_}/{C06_}/{C07_}/{C08_}/{C09_}/{C10_}/{C11_}/{C12_}/{C13_}/{C14_}/{C15_}/{C16_}/{C17_}/{C18_}/{C19_}/{C20_}" + 
"/{N01_}/{N02_}/{N03_}/{N04_}/{N05_}/{N06_}/{N07_}/{N08_}/{N09_}/{N10_}/{N11_}/{N12_}/{N13_}/{N14_}/{N15_}/{N16_}/{N17_}/{N18_}/{N19_}/{N20_}" +
"/{D01_}/{D02_}/{D03_}/{D04_}/{D05_}/{D06_}/{D07_}/{D08_}/{D09_}/{D10_}",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Back to asp.net core, when I try the following endpoint:

```
[Route(@"/MyHappyLittleController/{var1_}/{var2_}/{var3_}/{var4_}/{var5_}/{var6_}/{var7_} 
/{C01_}/{C02_}/{C03_}/{C04_}/{C05_}/{C06_}/{C07_}/{C08_}/{C09_}/{C10_}/{C11_}/{C12_}/{C13_}/{C14_}/{C15_}/{C16_}/{C17_}/{C18_}/{C19_}/{C20_}
/{N01_}/{N02_}/{N03_}/{N04_}/{N05_}/{N06_}/{N07_}/{N08_}/{N09_}/{N10_}/{N11_}/{N12_}/{N13_}/{N14_}/{N15_}/{N16_}/{N17_}/{N18_}/{N19_}/{N20_}
/{D01_}/{D02_}/{D03_}/{D04_}/{D05_}/{D06_}/{D07_}/{D08_}/{D09_}/{D10_}")]
```

... I get the following error messages:
["Route exceeds the maximum number of allowed segments of 28 and is unable to be processed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1LLZ.png)

Now, i can get this to work easily using endpoint routing and passing the parameters in as JSON, but the aim is to replace the current API with this new one, so I need to be able to accept all of these path segment parameters for the sake of backwards compatibility... **sigh**.

So, is anyone able to help me solve this? Is there a way?

Things I've tried:

- Endpoint routing with a manual path (same error)
- MVC routing (with compatability set to version 2.0), (Same error)

Is anyone able to solve this before I go mad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that is quite a troublesome API you need to migrate there. Of course, going forward, the *best* solution would be to replace that thing by a more modern one. But until you can do that, you will have to support this somehow.

So what you can do is use [catch-all parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-template-reference) to match the full URL and then parse those arguments yourself. The controller action could look like this:

```
[Route("/MyHappyLittleController/{**remainder}")]
public IActionResult DoStuff(string remainder)
{
    // remainder will be `var1/var2/var3/…` so you will need to split that
    string[] parameters = remainder.Split(new char[] { '/' });

    // validate the parameters and do something
    return Json(new { parameters });
}
```

This assumes that the individual parameters are simple enough that you can just split the string by the path separator. Since you now won’t have the route template parser running for this, you will have to validate these parameters yourself if you need to make sure that there is a certain number of them or that they contain valid values or types.

But this should still help you to get this working, even with that 28 path segments limitation.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, thanks! 
Tested and working correctly.
I've given multiple routes, so people can opt to use the old one for backwards compatibility, or a more modern one.
Thanks again :)

Comment: I hate that this is the answer, really shouldnt have an upper limit on these things. oh well. Thank you @poke